# arrange column data in R

Tags: r

My data set looks like below

```
ID     Diagnosis date    Procedure date
1      2005-09-09        2008-04-09
1      2006-05-09        2007-08-08
2      2007-07-02        2007-08-01
2      2007-07-02        2009-08-05
2      2008-05-8         2007-08-10
```

I want to group my data like below

```
ID      Diagnosis date     Procedure date
1       2005-09-09         2007-08-08
        2006-05-09         2008-04-09
2       2007-07-02         2007-08-01
                           2007-07-10
        2008-05-08         2009-08-05
```

Basically the procedure date should be after the diagnosis date

Comment: Great! Do you actually have spaces in your column names? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142189/sort-a-column-and-create-a-new-one

Comment: nope. there are no spaces in column names

Comment: I was trying to create a separate column to match with the diagnosis date

Comment: This isn't about arranging column data, it's about modifying data between columns. If your data is truly `Date` objects, then you should be able to solve your problem with `pmin` and `pmax`.

Comment: You'd probably be better off stacking this in a long form. `ID / Date / DateType` where `DateType` has two options - `"Diagnosis"` or `"Procedure"`. That way you could create a counter going down the page to identify each set of related events.

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution. Some sample data:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
ID     Diagnosis         Procedure
1      2005-09-09        2008-04-09
1      2006-05-09        2007-08-08
2      2007-07-02        2007-08-01
2      2007-07-02        2009-08-05
2      2008-05-08        2007-08-10')
```

Convert them to `Date` objects. (Since the strings are well-formatted, though, this might work just fine without converting them to dates. I guess it's just my habit to make it a "proper date object".)

```
dat$Diagnosis <- as.Date(dat$Diagnosis)
dat$Procedure <- as.Date(dat$Procedure)
```

`min` returns a single minimum value for a vector. `pmin` returns the pair-wise minima between vectors:

```
min(c(1,1,3,4), c(2,2,4,3))
# [1] 1
pmin(c(1,1,3,4), c(2,2,4,3))
# [1] 1 1 3 3
```

We can use that compare the two columns:

```
tmp1 <- pmin(dat$Diagnosis, dat$Procedure)
tmp2 <- pmax(dat$Diagnosis, dat$Procedure)
```

and store them back in-place:

```
dat$Diagnosis <- tmp1
dat$Procedure <- tmp2
```

Comment: Nope. Its not doing what I am expecting

Comment: Forgive my sarcasm, but ... with *that* clarity, I'm sure I can straighten things out right away. You only said *"procedure date should be after the diagnosis date"* **which this does**, but you apparently have unspoken requirements, too. Perhaps you have no problem mixing dates from different rows? Why does your first procedure go after the first diagnosis and not after the second? Why are your procedures not all ordered? Do you actually expect subsequent same `ID`s to be blank? Is this for data processing or just for display? You need to improve your question to get a better answer.

Comment: Good refs for reproducibility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Please take a quick look at those and think about how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following code solves:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(ID =  c(1,1,2,2,2), Diagnosis = c("2005-09-09","2006-05-09","2007-07-02","2007-07-02","2008-05-08"),
                   Procedure =  c("2008-04-09","2007-08-08","2007-08-01","2009-08-05","2007-08-10"))

data$Diagnosis <- as.Date(data$Diagnosis)
data$Procedure <- as.Date(data$Procedure)


data1 <- data[,-2] %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange( ID,Procedure)
out <- data.frame(data1,data[2])
out <- out[,c(1,3,2)]
out

ID  Diagnosis  Procedure
1  1 2005-09-09 2007-08-08
2  1 2006-05-09 2008-04-09
3  2 2007-07-02 2007-08-01
4  2 2007-07-02 2007-08-10
5  2 2008-05-08 2009-08-05
```